# How to make GUI in DOS?

Tags: gui, ms-dos

I want to make a GUI (Graphical User Interface) for DOS to complete my project. However, i don't know to make one.
I do not want it to be text based. I want it to be a true GUI like this one:
https://www.google.pt/search?q=make+DOS+gui&espv=2&biw=1440&bih=799&tbm=isch&imgil=MCa91TYVf0bFoM%253A%253BQYUL5lQvyw_UQM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Ffun500.brandoncornell.com%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=MCa91TYVf0bFoM%253A%252CQYUL5lQvyw_UQM%252C_&usg=__l7hU8BpLFWuGsstoMcPqiIwla00%3D&ved=0CDAQyjc&ei=bWZnVa-DPc38sAT67IPwCA#imgrc=MCa91TYVf0bFoM%253A%3BQYUL5lQvyw_UQM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Ffun500.brandoncornell.com%252FScreenshots%252FVer6%252F4.PNG%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Ffun500.brandoncornell.com%252F%3B1024%3B768

This is the programming languages that i allow completely:
Batch
C
This is the languages that i only accept if you can make a great thing with it:
C++
The other languages, are not accepted.
Also, i am posting in superuser beacuse stackoverflow only lets me post in next 2 days, so the closest one is superuser.

Comment: So you *know* this is off-topic but since you're question-banned from SO you decided to post here anyway? Also, no wonder you're banned if this is the general standard of your questions. Voted to close.

Comment: Im not question banned in Stackoverflow. Beacuse i have posted too many threads in there, i only can post a new thread in the next 4 days.

Comment: Then why can't you post there for 2 days? Edit: So it is 4 days in total. You *are* temp banned from SO clearly. Don't try to circumvent it by posting here.

Comment: this question isnt in the scope of SU. flagged to close.

Comment: There's no question here. You told us what you want to do, but didn't ask a specific question about it.

Comment: Fine, close this thread.

Comment: It sounds as though you're asking us to do your homework, and you give us no indication you have actually studied the material or begun trying solve this problem besides doing a basic web search for others who have done what you have been assigned to do. If you did a little work on your own and came up with questions about specific issues you could not figure out, you'd be much more likely to get a meaningful response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a DOS environment you can do a mode switch to enable graphics APIs to work.  This will enable mode switching

```
union REGS regs;

regs.h.ah = 0x00;  /* function 00h = mode set */
regs.h.al = 0x13;  /* 256-color */
int86(0x10,&regs,&regs); /* do it! */
```

More information on this can be found at http://www.brackeen.com/vga/basics.html